# Print pdf file using Adobe Reader without displaying the reader's window

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I am using this code to print pdf directly to the default printer:

```
Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/p /h D:myDocument.pdf";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.Start();
```

It is working but what i want is that the window of adobe reader will not show but it's still showing. How can i hide the adobe window? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you justify why it belongs here, all you have to do is finding the command line parameters for calling the Adobe Reader in the way you want, which is more suited for superuser.com

Comment: For print i recommend to use a third-party library which does not need the Acrobat reader. If paid solutions is suitable, then here is an example: [pdfium.net sdk - print functionality](http://pdfium.patagames.com/help/html/78b54dbd-9d15-4ba7-8138-0f2b8892fb86.htm)